# How to create sliding images like in application images in google play store

Tags: android

I am trying for long to figure out how the sliding images like in application images in google play store can be achieved. I gave a thought for ViewPager but view pager displays only one screen I want at least 3 to 4 images appearing on same screen and when i slide it should populate the next set of 3 images. I am not getting the way of how to achieve this.

Please provide me any links which can help me in achieving this

The screenshot from application images in google play store is as follows for facebook app:[image]

In the above screenshot there are two images simultaneously visible and also are horizontally swipeable.

Comment: yup... Forgot to mention facebook app images screenshot on google play store..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and set orientation horizontal like this :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView rvSlide = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvSlide);
rvSlide.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Use ImageView as a RecyclerView item and you get what you want.

Comment: I am able to get the horizontal listview but i want like two or three list item should be visible on the screen. Right now only one list is getting visible

Comment: @anand Set the list item width to fix size to show more than one item on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options really:

The first is using a ViewPager and overriding the getPageWidth(int position) method in your adapter. This still acts like a ViewPager in that it will snap the current item to the middle.

The other option is to use a RecyclerView with a horizontal-orientation LinearLayoutManager, which will act more like the Play Store version (not snapping to an image)